# php: how to decode a mix of hex and string?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I have this string

```
&#87;i&#108;&#108;ek&#101;&#110;&#115;&#109;o&#108;e&#110;&#115;t&#114;a&#97;&#116;122;&#51;5&#48;&#48;&nbsp;&#72;A&#83;&#83;EL&#84;
```

Which gives once printed out in HTML should be: "Willekensmolenstraat 122 3500 HASSELT"

How can I decode it ?

I found that function

```
function decodeHexas($source) {
    return preg_replace('/&#([a-f0-9]+);/mei', 'chr(0x\\1)', $source);
}
```

But it does not give the right result

Comment: [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)?

Comment: PHP has many built-in functions for dealing with HTML data.  You will probably never need to write code to manipulate HTML data yourself manually.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$input = '&#87;i&#108;&#108;ek&#101;&#110;&#115;&#109;o&#108;e&#110;&#115;t&#114;a&#97;&#116;122;&#51;5&#48;&#48;&nbsp;&#72;A&#83;&#83;EL&#84;';

function decode_entities($text) {
    // decode decimal notation (html_entity_decode() will work, too)  
    $text = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me',"chr(\\1)", $text); 

    // the string contains ";" and "&nbsp", let's modify it a bit
    $text = preg_replace("/([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+);([0-9]+)\&nbsp;(\w+)/", "$1 $2 $3 $4", $text);

    return $text;
}

echo decode_entities($input);

// Result: 
// Willekensmolenstraat 122 3500 HASSELT
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@castis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28819649/3653989) say you can use html_entity_decode()

```
<?php

$string = "&#87;i&#108;&#108;ek&#101;&#110;&#115;&#109;o&#108;e&#110;&#115;t&#114;a&#97;&#116;122;&#51;5&#48;&#48;&nbsp;&#72;A&#83;&#83;EL&#84;";

echo html_entity_decode($string);

?>
```

You can read more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: @yarek you got some advance?